# An English equivalent of 'intelligentsia'?

Tags: single-word-requests

[Webster says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intelligentsia):

> Definition of INTELLIGENTSIA:
>   
>   intellectuals who form an artistic, social, or political vanguard or elite
>
> Origin of INTELLIGENTSIA
>   
>   Russian intelligentsiya, from Latin intelligentia intelligence
>   
>   First Known Use: 1907

What other word or (a group of words) would describe in English the same thing?

Comment: Intelligentsia **is** an English word. You can find synonyms for it in a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/intelligentsia).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the nice answers found in the possibly-duplicate question, [Simple word related to “a group of intellectuals” or “a group of smart learners”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32716), include *[cognoscenti](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cognoscenti#Noun)*, *[boffins](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boffins)*, *[eggheads](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eggheads)*, *[brains trust](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brains_trust)*, etc.

Comment: As a Russian person, I think that none of these words describe INTELLIGENTSIA fully. Intelligentsia is not only about being educated, but also about being decent and well-raised (have good manners). Also, this word doesn't necessarily mean the person has high IQ or possesses some specific skills. Also, I don't consider this question a duplicate, because "a group of intellectuals or smart learners" is not completely equal to Intelligentsia.

Comment: @Highstaker, if the question had asked for an English equivalent of *интеллигенция* or of Russian *intelligyentsia* and defined it as in your comment, then we'd have realized it wasn't asking the same thing as previous question.  However, in terms of usual meaning in English of [intelligentsia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intelligentsia#Noun), “The intellectual élite of a society...”, it's mostly a duplicate.  Edit the question appropriately and I'll vote to reopen

Comment: I suppose it will be better to post a separate question about my definition of it, since I'm not entirely sure which definition the original author meant. Though, I'm not sure if it should be posted here or in Russian.SE

Comment: @Highstaker, I wasn't aware of Russian.SE.  You might get a better response there.  In ELU translation questions are often treated as off-topic.  Eg, http://english.stackexchange.com/faq says "Translation and non-English languages" are  “out of scope”.  BTW, if you post related question in Russian.SE, please edit a link to it, in this question.